# AppendDictation on Microsoft Speech Platform 11 (Server)?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi, speech-to-text

I'm relatively new to both C# and the Microsoft Speech platform, but I am working on a server application that will need to transcribe free dictation.  The MS Speech Platform SDK seemed perfect, and works on the server, unless i reference the AppendDictation() method in GrammarBuilder.

I am using the Microsoft Speech Platform SDK 11, and the application works fine if I define a grammar, but the moment I add in AppendDictation(), I am met with this error:

```
Cannot find grammar referenced by this grammar.
```

Even this sample from the documentation seems to fail:

```
GrammarBuilder startStop = new GrammarBuilder();
GrammarBuilder dictation = new GrammarBuilder();
dictation.AppendDictation();

startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("StartDictation", new SemanticResultValue("Start Dictation",true)));
startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("DictationInput", dictation));
startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("StopDictation", new SemanticResultValue("Stop Dictation", false)));
Grammar grammar=new Grammar(startStop);
grammar.Enabled=true;
grammar.Name=" Free-Text Dictation ";
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(grammar);
```

Oddly, if I change LoadGrammar to LoadGrammarAsync, the grammar loads (or at least the event handler is called), but then the recoginzer fails with this error:

```
Error: At least one grammar must be loaded before doing a recognition.
```

I've read that the server version of the platform does not support dictation, but it seems odd that it would ship with a method that just doesn't work.  Has anyone managed to get a dictation grammar to work on the server?  What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this in the future -- I've now emailed back and forth with Microsoft, and ultimately received this response:

> The managed interfaces (Microsoft.Speech and System.Speech) are built
>   on top of the native SAPI interfaces.  These interfaces are the same
>   for both the Server engine and the Desktop engine.
>
> BUT the engine
>   itself is responsible for implementing dictation, and the Server
>   engine does not do so.  Therefore, the call will fail when you load
>   the grammar.

Not the answer I was hoping for, but it does explain it.

Comment: Is there any other way to do dictation then?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `System.Speech` you can load you grammar with `_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());` , and it will work well. The recognition is not bad, but then you have to use a 16KHz PCM wave file or other compatible wave file configurations. Sadly the `DictationGrammar()` is not available with `Microsoft.Speech`.